# Is Allure report supported by Travis?

Tags: testing, build, automated-tests, travis-ci, allure

I couldn't find any information about integration of Allure report with Travis. 
Is it possible to generate Allure report on Travis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travis doesn't have the integration with Allure reports. But it's possible to generate the report and then send it to the hosting server where you can host and browse it.